# How is this type parameter 'typed'?

Tags: scala

In the method signature for groupBy :

```
def groupBy[K](f : (A) => K) : Map[K, This]
```

How is the type parameter of [K] on groupBy typed ? What is the significance of [k] in this context : groupBy[K] . Why is the type parameter required here, is this a requirement of Scala that cannot use instead : `def groupBy(f : (A) => K) : Map[K, This]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
How is the type parameter of [K] on groupBy typed ?
```

From the type of the function passed to `groupBy`, unless passed explicitly.

```
What is the significance of [k] in this context : groupBy[K] .
```

It is a type parameter: a type that is not fixed at the definition site of `groupBy`, but, instead, varies and depends on the context at each usage site of this method.

```
Why is the type parameter required here, is this a requirement of Scala that cannot use instead : `def groupBy(f : (A) => K) : Map[K, This]` ?
```

It is a requirement. In the definition you provide, the function passed to `groupBy` must be from `A` (a type parameter of the class) to `K`, a fixed type known at the definition of `groupBy`. Since there's no type `K` in Scala, that would automatically an error.

Or, to put in another way, it would be like defining `groupBy` as `def groupBy(f: (A) => String): Map[String, This]`.

Comment: "must be from A (a type parameter of the class) " by this are you saying that the type A is a type of the class that the groupBy method is contained in ?

Comment: @Adrian I wouldn't word it like this, but if I understand what you are saying correctly, yes. `A` is the type parameter of the particular instance of the class that `groupBy` is in. So, if it's a `List[String]`, then `A` is `String`.

Answer (score 1):

K is a method level type parameter, it does not exist for the class. so what you propose would not make sense. K needs to be declared as a type parameter also, because im assuming you do not want to reference type K, but rather the type variable K.

Comment: To clarify, `groupBy[K]` declares type parameter `K`, which is referenced in types (type constructors) `(A) => K` (which is sugar for `Function1[A, K]`) and `Map[K, This]`. Without declaring `K` as a type parameter, `K` would refer to a type in an outer scope in the same way that `Map` or `Int` do. In this case under typical usage, the type `K` is inferred from the return type of the provided `(A) => K` - the map key selector.

Answer (score 0):

The List is defined in the scaladoc as `sealed abstract class List[+A]` - so A is the type of elements in the list. You can group the list's elements by any function `f: (A) ⇒ K`, which is to say that K can be any type. If you are going to notify the compiler that you can group by "a function `f: (A) ⇒ K`, where K is some type", you need to declare the symbol K. This is done at the method level, because K is only used at the method level. This is accomplished by declaring `def groupBy[K](f: (A) ⇒ K): Map[K, List[A]]`. Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 0):

K is specified first because the type of the KeySelector function, (A) => K, and the type of the result :Map[K, this] depend on its definition. K is the type parameter that allows the groupBy implementation to abstract over grouping by a Key of any type.